# How to make Windows Authentication to work for only for specific members in the organization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I am creating an **Intranet Website which uses Windows Authentication**.

I want to use it for only **certain specific members of my organization.** I have a line of code in my _LogOnPartial.cshtml page

```
**<text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!     [ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>**
```

But when my manager runs the website from my organization he will see a welcome message like - Welcome **MYORGANIZATIONDOMAIN\MyManagersUserName**,

when my fried runs it from my organization he will see a message like - **MYORGANIZATIONDOMAIN\FriendsUserName**,

anyone accessing the website will see the welcome message with the user name.

**I DON'T WANT this to happen**. I want to show the welcome message only to **CERTAIN SPECIFIC MEMBERS of my organization**; for others it should not show a welcome message.

**How can I achive this?**